# How to create a heatmap to display matching and not matching data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have some parcel data that shows which city the volume of parcels belongs to.

```
+---------+-------------+----------------+
| Volume  |   City      | Foreign_City   |
+---------+-------------+----------------+
|     200 | Chicago     | New York       |
|     300 | Los Angeles | NaN            |
|     100 | San Diego   | Dallas         |
|     100 | Chicago     | NaN            |
+---------+-------------+----------------+
```

For example, 1st row states that 200 parcels that were originally destined for Chicago in fact belong to New York.(Same logic for 3rd row). Whereas, the second row demonstrates that 300 parcels belong to Los Angeles(Same logic for 4th row).

My dataset contains over 50k cities and foreign cities.

I can think of viewing this as a heatmap, but am not certain how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Given the existing data, when there's a match between `'City'` and `'Foreign_City'`, there are three options depending on your desired plot.

  1. Use `.fillna` in `'Foreign_City'` with the corresponding row from `'City'`.

     - The heatmap will have all data, showing the `'Volume'` for correct and incorrect delivery locations.
  2. Use `.dropna` to drop the entire row when there's a `'NaN'` in `'Foreign_City'`

     - The heatmap will show the `'Volume'` for all incorrectly delivered parcels.
  3. Keep only the correctly delivered parcel data

  - In the case of (2) and (3), plot a separate heatmap for each.
- [`.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) will be used to shape the data for plotting, which will deal with cases where there's duplicate `'City'` - `'Foreign_City'` pairs.
- **Tested in `python 3.8`, `pandas 1.3.1`, `seaborn 0.11.1`, and `matplotlib 3.4.2`**.

### Imports and Load Data

```py
import panda as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load the data
data = {'Volume': [200, 300, 100, 100, 25], 'City': ['Chicago', 'Los Angeles', 'San Diego', 'Chicago', 'Los Angeles'], 'Foreign_City': ['New York', np.nan, 'Dallas', np.nan, np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# display(df)
   Volume         City Foreign_City
0     200      Chicago     New York
1     300  Los Angeles          NaN
2     100    San Diego       Dallas
3     100      Chicago          NaN
4      25  Los Angeles          NaN
```

### All Data

```
# fillna and keep all
df.Foreign_City = df.Foreign_City.fillna(df.City)

# sum repeat pair and shape the dataframe for plotting as a heatmap
dfp = df.pivot_table(index='City', columns='Foreign_City', values='Volume', aggfunc='sum')

# plot the dataframe
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
sns.heatmap(data=dfp, ax=ax, annot=True, cmap='GnBu_r', fmt='0.0f')
_ = ax.set(title='All Deliveries')
```

[image]

### Separate Data

```py
# or dropna and keep only incorrect deliveries
incorrect = df.dropna()
icp = incorrect.pivot_table(index='City', columns='Foreign_City', values='Volume', aggfunc='sum')

# or only correct deliveries
correct = df[df.Foreign_City.isna()].copy()
correct.Foreign_City = correct.Foreign_City.fillna(correct.City)
cp = correct.pivot_table(index='City', columns='Foreign_City', values='Volume', aggfunc='sum')

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(8, 10))
sns.heatmap(data=cp, ax=ax[0], annot=True, cmap='GnBu_r', fmt='0.0f')
ax[0].set(title='Correct Deliveries')

sns.heatmap(data=icp, ax=ax[1], annot=True, cmap='GnBu_r', fmt='0.0f')
ax[1].set(title='Incorrect Deliveries')

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]